# PHP+JS Form - Paste page URL into the email form after submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I have a basic form and after sending the form I need to insert the URL of the page into the e-mail so that I know where the user filled in the form.

I tried more options that I found in this forum, but unfortunately none of them worked.

How do I edit the code to send it correctly and add the URL to the email.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

```js
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function(event) {
  if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    //handle the invalid form...
    formError();
    submitContactFormMSG(false, "Vyplňte prosím formulář správně!");
  } else {

    var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;

    if (filter.test($("#formphone").val())) {
      //everything looks good!
      event.preventDefault();
      submitcontactForm();
    } else {
      submitContactFormMSG(false, "Vložte prosím správný telefon!");
      return false;
    }
  }
});

function submitcontactForm() {
  //Variables With Form Content
  var formfname = $("#formfname").val();
  var formlname = $("#formlname").val();
  var formemail = $("#formemail").val();
  var formphone = $("#formphone").val();
  var forminfo = $("#forminfo").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/forms/kontaktni-formular.php",
    data: "&formfname=" + formfname + "&formlname=" + formlname + "&formemail=" + formemail + "&formphone=" + formphone + "&forminfo=" + forminfo,
    success: function(text) {
      if (text == "success") {
        contactFormSuccess();
      } else {
        formError();
        submitContactFormMSG(false, text);
      }
    }
  });
}

function contactFormSuccess() {
  $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
  submitContactFormMSG(true, "Vaše zpráva byla úspěšně odeslána :-)")
}

function formError() {
  $(".help-block.with-errors").removeClass('hidden');
}

function submitContactFormMSG(valid, msg) {
  if (valid) {
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center col-12 text-success";
  } else {
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center col-12 text-danger";
  }
  $("#msgContactFormSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#msgContactFormSubmit").offset().top - 80
    },
    'slow');
}
```

```css
.form-control {
  border: 1px solid #99CC33;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.has-error .form-control {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}

.help-block {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
}

label:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="row" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
  <div id="msgContactFormSubmit" class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row pad">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="formfname"><strong>Jméno</strong><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></label>
        <input name="formfname" id="formfname" placeholder="YYY" class="form-control" type="text" required data-error="Vložte jméno">
      </div>
      <!-- end form-group -->
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="formlname"><strong>Příjmení</strong><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></label>
        <input name="formlname" id="formlname" placeholder="XXX" class="form-control" type="text" required data-error="Vložte příjmení">
      </div>
      <!-- end form-group -->
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="formemail"><strong>E-mailová adresa</strong><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></label>
        <input name="formemail" id="formemail" placeholder="xxx@yyy.cz" pattern=".*@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}" class="form-control" type="email" required data-error="Vložte odpovídající e-mail">
      </div>
      <!-- end form-group -->
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="formphone"><strong>Telefonní číslo</strong><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></label>
        <input name="formphone" id="formphone" placeholder="+420 XXXXXXXXX" pattern="^\+?\d{9,16}" class="form-control" type="text" required data-error="Vložte správné telefonní číslo">
      </div>
      <!-- end form-group -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="forminfo"><strong>Další informace</strong></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Informace" name="forminfo" id="forminfo" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!-- end form-group -->
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-shutter-out-horizontal col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">ODESLAT</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In PHP I have this:

```
<?php
$errormsg = "";
if (empty($_POST["formfname"])) { $errormsg .= "Jméno je povinné. ";} else {$formfname = $_POST["formfname"];}
if (empty($_POST["formlname"])) {$errormsg .= "Příjmení je povinné. ";} else {$formlname = $_POST["formlname"];}
if (empty($_POST["formemail"])) {$errormsg .= "Email je povinný. ";} else {$formemail = $_POST["formemail"];}
if (empty($_POST["formphone"])) {$errormsg .= "Telefonní číslo je povinné ";} else {$formphone = $_POST["formphone"];}

$success = '';
$body_message = '';
if (!$errormsg){
    $headers =  'From: '. $formfname .' '. $formlname .' <'. $email .'>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
                'Content-type: text/html; windows-1250' ;
    $to = "xxx@yyy.cz";
    $subject = "Kontaktní formulář";

    //telo mailu
    $body_message .= "<strong>Jméno:</strong> " . $formfname."<br>\n";
    $body_message .= "<strong>Přímení:</strong> " . $formlname."<br>\n";
    $body_message .= "<strong>E-mailová adresa:</strong> " . $formemail."<br>\n";
    $body_message .= "<strong>Telefon:</strong> " . $formphone."<br>\n";
    $body_message .= "<strong>Další informace:</strong> " . $forminfo."<br>\n";

    $success = @mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
}

if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "Něco se pokazilo: " . $errormsg;
}?>
```

Comment: `so that I know where the user filled in the form.`...why, have you got multiple forms? Or it's displayed on multiple pages you mean? Probably makes sense to include a page ID or something as a hidden field in the form when you generate it

Comment: use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the refer URL (as you are sending the form request vai ajax).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP. Let's say your adress is `https://example.com/foo.php?id=1`. Then `HTTP_HOST`returns `example.com` and `REQUEST_URI` returns `/bar.php?id=1`.
There are two options:

---

**First option, use PHP**. That only works if the PHP code is on the same site as the form though.  It could look like this:

```
$body_message .= "<strong>Site:</strong> ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>\n";
```

And instead of using the url you could simply use anything you want which might be more readable. Like:

```
$body_message .= "<strong>Site:</strong> Get more information about us<br>\n";
```

---

**Second option, use hidden form field.**

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '<input type="hidden" name="formurl" id="formurl" value="'.$url.'">';
```

Obviously you have to add the new form field to your Javascript as well:

```
var formurl= $("#formurl").val();
//other code...
data: "&formfname=" + formfname + "&formlname=" + formlname + "&formemail=" + formemail + "&formphone=" + formphone + "&forminfo=" + forminfo + "&formurl=" + formurl,
//other code...
```

Edit: You have to edit the PHP file nonetheless. Otherwise the script doesn't know that there is another form field. It's only two more lines:

```
<?php
//There's a new form field, so tell PHP it's there. No $errormsg is needed because it has nothing to do with the user input
if (empty($_POST["formurl"])) {$formurl = "no url given";} else {$formurl= $_POST["formurl"];}

//other code...

//Then append the URL to the message
$body_message .= "<strong>Site:</strong> ".$formurl."<br>\n";
```

---

That said, I'd always prefer the first option over the second. As all input fields, the user can easily manipulate the value of hidden form fields. So even if he sends it from example.com/contact.php, in the mail it seems as if it was sent from example.com/thisurldoesnotexist.php. The second solution can be an option if e.g. the php code is on a different site than the html form.

Comment: I am not a developer so sorry in advance. I can work only with html and css. So PHP and JS i trial and error.

I need to use second option because I am not able combine HTML form code with PHP even though that would probably be a better option.

In second option I put all things from your JS snippets to my main.js, but If i put your snippet of php code to kontaktni-formular.php, it does not work.

Comment: I didn't know that you don't know any PHP. I added more information about the second option. You still have to add a little bit of PHP code because if you don't tell the PHP script that there is a new form field which it should put into the mail, it won't do it by itself. Basically you just add a new field. First in the html (put info into a form field | it's not visible thanks to "hidden"), then in the Javascript (send form | you don't NEED javascript for sending forms but you used it anyway) and lastly in the PHP (get information and send mail).

Comment: I added everything to my files (first code to HTML, second to JS and last to PHP). Every field is ok after submit, but SITE is undefined - https://www.havic.cz/test

Comment: What is the file extension of your test file? It must be .php, otherwise PHP code will not work in it. If it is an html file, you cannot use PHP and you have to add the URL (or site name) manually instead. For example: <input type="hidden" name="formurl" id="formurl" value="test">

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I understand. So I will work with value="url site" and put URL every time manually. At first I thought it will work automatically (somehow)